# Synthetic fusional morphology

Tags: morphology

Are there other languages, apart from those in the indo-european and semitic language families, that have synthetic-fusional morphologies?  It seems that the synthetic-agglutinative morphologies are much more common (eg. uralic, altaic, caucasian, basque, hurrian, sumerian, etruscan)

Answer (score 2):

The WALS website enumerates and classifies some languages having a fusional morphology: https://wals.info/chapter/20.

Still on WALS, some statistics are given about the degree of exponence of a few languages: https://wals.info/chapter/21

Indeed, from this sample, it seems agglutinative morphology is much more common.